# splits strings in java in different manner

Tags: java, string, split

I am very new to java. i want to splits the string into following manner.
suppose i have given a string input like  sample 1 `jayesh =10 vyas =13 harshit=10; and so on` as a input
sample 2: `harsh=2, vyas=5;`

now i want to store `jayesh, vyas, harshit from sample 1 and harsh , vyas from sample 2(all this type of strings which are just before the assignment operator)` into string or char array.

so can anyone please tell me about that how to do this in java. i know about split method in java, but in this case there are multiple strings i have to store.

Comment: You can still use split(), but you'll have to then split each result.

Comment: Which problem with `String.split(regex)` are you having? How are the individual elements structured? Is it always `name=numeric_value name=numeric_value ...` or are they separated by `;`, are there non-numeric values etc.? As an alternative to `split()` you could use  `Pattern` and `Matcher` directly and match and extract the words in front of the `=`.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `=\\d+;?` regex

`=\\d+;?` match `=` and as many digits with `;` as optional

```
    String s="jayesh =10 vyas =13 harshit=10;";
    String[] ss=s.split("=\\d+;?");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));
```

output

```
[jayesh ,  vyas ,  harshit]
```

---

To extend it further you can use `\\s*=\\d+[,;]?\\s*`

`\\s*` : match zero or more spaces

`[,;]?` match any character mention in the list as optional

but if you want to **avoid any special character** after digits then use

`\\s*=\\d+\\W*"` :

`\\s*=` : match zero or more spaces and `=` character

`\\d+`  : match one or more digits

`\W*`   : match zero or more non-word character except `a-zA-z0-9_`

```
    String s="harsh=2, vyas=5; vyas=5";
    String s2 ="jayesh =10 vyas=13 harshit=10;";
    String regex="\\s*=\\d+\\W*";
    String[] ss=s.split(regex);
    String[] ss2=s2.split(regex);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss2));
```

output

```
[harsh, vyas, vyas]
[jayesh, vyas, harshit]
```

**Note :** Space after `,` is added for formatting by the `Arrays.toString` function though there is no space in the `ss` and `ss2` array elements.

For `Hashset` use

```
    Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(ss));
```

Comment: Add a little whitespace to the expression and he should be fine ... unless the input can look differently, e.g. like the newly added sample 2 which contains a comma.

Comment: can i store this strings in hashset or set to avoid duplicacy ??? suppose if i have two same strings name jayesh and another is also jayesh then i want to store only single string.

Comment: @JayeshVyas  yes you can do this `Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(ss));` and for further reading , you can go through [oracle regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)  and try `character classes` and `predefined character classes`

Comment: @Thomas actually i tried this regex in the beginning , just forgot that `Arrays.toString(ss2)` will add spaces for formatting and it left me wondering why the spaces aren't removed :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use replaceAll() to get the expected results

```
String stringToSearch = "jayesh =10 vyas =13 harshit=10;";  

stringToSearch = stringToSearch.replaceAll("=\\d+;?","");

System.out.println(stringToSearch);   

output:
jayesh  vyas  harshit
```

Comment: OP , i want to store `jayesh, vyas, .... all this type of strings` which are just before the assignment operator) into `string or char array` and nice regex